# Перехват вывода консольного приложения

Tags: c#, winforms

Всем доброго утра!
Суть в чем: есть такое консольное приложение (скрипт Perl)

```
for($x=0; $x<20; $x++) {
    print "$x\n";
    sleep 1;
}
```

Нужно перехватить его вывод в TextBox WinForms приложения.

Мой код:

```
Process _procPerl;

private void bStartProc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _procPerl = new Process();
    _procPerl.StartInfo.FileName = "perl.exe";
    _procPerl.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    _procPerl.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    _procPerl.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    _procPerl.StartInfo.Arguments = tbParams.Text;
    _procPerl.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    _procPerl.Exited += _procPerl_Exited;
    _procPerl.OutputDataReceived += _procPerl_OutputDataReceived;
    if (_procPerl.Start())
    {
        _procPerl.BeginOutputReadLine();
        bStopProc.Enabled = true;
        bStartProc.Enabled = false;
    }
}

void _procPerl_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Action Exited = delegate() {
        bStopProc.Enabled = false;
        bStartProc.Enabled = true;
    };
    Invoke(Exited);
}

void _procPerl_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Action<object> Received = delegate(object s) {
        if(s != null)
            tbOutput.AppendText(s.ToString() + Environment.NewLine); 
    };
    Invoke(Received, (object)e.Data);
}

private void bStopProc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_procPerl != null && !_procPerl.HasExited)
        _procPerl.Kill();
    bStopProc.Enabled = false;
    bStartProc.Enabled = true;
}
```

Проблема в том, что _procPerl_OutputDataReceived срабатывает только после завершения процесса _procPerl, а надо, чтобы срабатывало по мере реального вывода (чтобы выводило как в консоли, каждая строка через одну секунду, см. код Perl).

Answer (score 1):

Помогло отключение буферизации вывода в скрипте Perl:

$| = 1;

Answer (score 0):

Вот работающий код на VB.NET:

```vb
Dim Info As New ProcessStartInfo With {.FileName = "smth.exe", .Arguments = "some args", .RedirectStandardOutput = True, .RedirectStandardError = True, .UseShellExecute = False, .CreateNoWindow = True}
Dim Prc As Process = Process.Start(Info)

Do
  Dim Line As String = Await Prc.StandardOutput.ReadLineAsync()
  If Line Is Nothing Then Exit Do
  RtbStart1.Text += Line + vbCrLf
Loop
```

Comment: VB.NET? О боже.

Comment: @Vlad, и чем же он тебе не угодил?

Comment: Ну, довольно экзотический язык. Не говоря о том, что автор вопроса в тэгах указал именно C#.

Comment: Он ничем не хуже шарпа. Возможности те же, переписывается элементарно. Раз уж у меня есть котовый код на VB.NET, то почему бы его не привести?

Comment: Например, потому, что автор явно указал, что хочет C#, а перевести между языками для вас наверняка тривиально. Насчёт «ничем не хуже», по факту бейсик у нас существенно менее популярен (в отличие от англоязычной традиции, да).