# Как получить стандартный поток стороннего консольного приложения (C#)

Tags: c#, процесс

Есть несколько вспомогательных консольных приложений. Ими мне нужно управлять с главного консольного приложения.Для этого нужно читать и писать информацию в их поток ввода\вывода. 
Всё что пишет запускаемое приложение, должно перенаправляться в запускающее, тоже самое и с вводом.

Пока я реализовал только запуск стороннего приложения таким образом.

```
Process process = new Process();

        // Configure the process using the StartInfo properties.
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "1.exe";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-i";
        process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        process.Start();                    
        process.WaitForExit();      // Waits here for the process to exit.             
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Перехват вывода консольного приложения](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/427407/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%85%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Comment: @Serj-Tm не дубликат - там была проблема жанра "телепатическая отладка" с конкретным дочерним процессом, тут же общий вопрос "как сделать"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Разобрался сам. Спасибо всем ответившим. Ниже код который помогает реализовать мою задачу максимально просто.

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "program.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "arguments";
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;            

process.Start();
Console.WriteLine(process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
process.WaitForExit();      // Waits here for the process to exit.
```

Comment: Не забудьте отметить свой ответ в качестве решения через 2 дня. Ну и еще было бы неплохо переписать из документации ключевые моменты - ответы-ссылки на этом сайте обычно не приветствуются.

Answer (score 5):

Был у меня такой примерчик запуска приложени и перенаправления его потоков ввода-вывода на управление от программы.

```
Process ConnectProcess
StreamReader RPIReader;
StreamWriter RPIWriter;

ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("rpitest.exe", FindedAddr.ToString() + " -s");
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.ASCII;
psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
ConnectProcess = Process.Start(psi);
RPIReader = ConnectProcess.StandardOutput;
RPIWriter = ConnectProcess.StandardInput;
RPIWriter.AutoFlush = true;

//запускаем поток чтения
ReadThread = new Thread(ThreadReadingFunc);
ReadThread.Start();
```